# jQuery Click not working on iScroll 4?

Tags: jquery, iscroll4, iscroll

I have this bit of code which [iScoll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) displays correctly:

```
<ul id="thelist">
<li id="1">Option 1</li>
<li id="2">Option 2</li>
<li id="3">Option 3</li>
<li id="4">Option 4</li>
</ul>
```

but when I use this jQuery code it doesn't work:

```
$("li").click(function(){
alert($(this).text());
});
```

and the most curious part is that this bit of code works:

```
$("#thelist").click(function(){
alert($(this).text());
});
```

Someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to write this; I'd try with `.on()` and see what happens:

```
$('#thelist').on({

    click: function () { alert($(this).text()); }

}, 'li');
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fQEHm/) to test with.

Comment: ok, very cool! .click() binds the event when the function triggers (most likely in your case it's when you run the .ready() function) and if the li elements are populated after the page triggers .ready() then the events don't register. Using .on() solves that because it registers the event even before the elements li are rendered, which is what I think was causing the problem. Use .on() when working with HTML that changes dynamically during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$("#thelist").children("li").click(function() { ...`